# When I add a padding prop to a Box on MUI it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I'm using MUI version 4.11.0 and when I try to add a padding to a Box component using the 'p' prop it doesn't work.

`<Box p={4}>{children}</Box>`

It works on other projects but not on the one I'm currently working on. I'm currently working on a react v18 project with vite. Every other component other than the Box component works fine. When I inspect the div that's supposed to have the box styles, I get: [image]

The classes aren't applying any styles.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

I looked at the docs, tried re-compiling, inspected the component on dev tools.

Comment: Are you only seeing this issue in development in StrictMode? The MUI v4 styling engine does not support StrictMode.